# Get error when convert timestamp into datetime in Rails 4

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, unix-timestamp

In `rails 4`, i try to convert `datetime into timestamp` and display time on it but get error.

```
d = '2015/09/15T10:25:02.840Z'
tt = DateTime.parse(d).strftime('%Q')
abort Time.at(tt.to_i)

Error: no implicit conversion of Time into String
```

Any one have a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`abort` takes string as an argument. This should be alright

```
abort Time.at(tt.to_i/1000).to_s
```

Also note that strftime `%Q` converts to milliseconds. You should divide `tt` with 1000 in order to get the right time.